# Can an Eevee evolve from an already evolved form of Eevee?

Tags: pokemon

For example, can a Vaporeon evolve into a Glaceon due to water becoming ice, or can a Jolteon evolve into a Espeon because I guess electricity turns into lasers or something. Or maybe a Flareon could evolve into a Vaporeon if fire got hot enough to become a laser, or a Flareon could turn into a Umbreon if it lost its fire or whatever?

Can an Eevee evolve after already evolving?

Answer (score 9):

One other place where a similar effect is possible is in the TCG. By using cards such as Devolution Spray

[image]

or certain Pokémon such as the Jolteon, Flareon and Vaporeon from Rising Rivals

[image]

you can devolve an already evolved Pokémon back into an Eevee, then evolve it into a different form of Eevee instead.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know how canonical this is, but to my knowledge, there is one instance of an Eevee going through multiple evolutions. In the *[Pokemon Adventures](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Adventures)* manga, the character Red has an [Eevee](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Vee) that has the capability of freely transforming into Jolteon/Flareon/Vaporeon, but this ability is due to Team Rocket experimentation<sup>1</sup>, and really it's still just an Eevee with some enhanced abilities. The transformation is incredibly painful as well.

It subsequently evolves **permanently** into an Espeon.

<sup>1</sup> This is part of their experiment to control Moltres, Zapdos, and Articuno, who they then [fuse into a mega-bird](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/PS033), so take this as you will.

Answer (score 3):

No, I do not believe this has happened, either in the anime or in the games. Evolution is more than just an aura that surrounds a standard Eevee. Their whole physical form has changed, and a Flareon whose fire had gone out would be no more a Vaporeon than a Charizard whose fire had gone out (as happens in the anime) would be a Blastoise. It is worth noting that there are moves that can change types, like Soak, which changes the target's type to Water. However, this move does not change a Flareon or other Eevee evolution into a Vaporeon.